# How to wait for other epics to complete and then invoke a callback?

Tags: redux-observable

I'm trying to map multiple actions in a first epic, handle them in a second epic, and then invoke a callback in the first one.

Here's the flow as I see it:

1. The fetchMultipleOperationsEpic listens for OPERATIONS_FETCH_ALL and
   creates a stream of fetchOperations actions.
2. Then the fetchOperationsEpic kicks in, fetching data with
   fetchOperationData for each dispatched action.
3. After data for each operation is fetched, the
   fetchMultipleOperationsEpic should invoke a callback.

```js
const fetchMultipleOperationsEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType(OPERATIONS_FETCH_ALL),
    switchMap(({ payload }) => {
        const stream = of(...payload.ids.map(processId => fetchOperations({ processId })));

        // PROBLEM HERE: 'done' is logged before actions from fetchOperationsEpic complete
        return stream.pipe(finalize(() => console.log('done')))
    })
)

const fetchOperationsEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType(OPERATIONS_FETCH),
    mergeMap(({ payload }) => fetchOperationData(payload.processId))
)

const fetchOperationData = processId => {
    api.fetchOperationsByProcess(processId).pipe(
        mergeMap(operations => of(fetchSuccess(), fooAction(), barAction())),
        catchError(error => of(fetchOperationsFailure({ processId, error })))
    )
}
```

Also tried with forkJoin with no success:

```js
const fetchMultipleOperationsEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType(OPERATIONS_FETCH_ALL),
    switchMap(({ payload }) => {
        const observables = [...payload.ids.map(processId => of(fetchOperations({ processId })))];

        // Doesn't wait as well
        return forkJoin(observables).pipe(
            mergeMap(o => o),
            finalize(() => console.log('done'))
        )
    })
)
```

In fact, the only way I made it work is to avoid calling fetchOperations actions (thus avoid invoking the fetchOperationsEpic), and call fetchOperationData directly:

```js
const fetchMultipleOperationsEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType(OPERATIONS_FETCH_ALL),
    mergeMap(({ payload }) => {
        const observables = [...payload.ids.map(id => fetchOperationData(id))];
        return merge(...observables)
            .pipe(finalize(() => console.log('done')))
    })
)
```

Which is fine. I just wondered if my initial approach is actually possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you think you have a "problem here":

```js
return stream.pipe(finalize(() => console.log('done')))
```

That's actually behaving correctly. The `finalize` will run *immediately after* the list of actions returned by the `of` directly above it are *dispatched* to the store. That's because you've explicitly chained the `finalize` to that inner observable.

The issue with the approach you're thinking is that, once an action goes to the store, it's no longer in the scope of that specific observable. You *can't* simply wait for processing of a particular action in other epics to end because, ultimately, epics never really end. In the strict RxJS sense, the observables never emit a *complete notification*.

Generally, I would recommend looking into a solution that uses a single epic (maybe along the lines of your last example). That allows you to simply chain operators, such as `finalize`, without needing to jump through too many hoops. You can still refactor your code so that the epic makes use of reusable functions in case you want to share/duplicate business logic between different epics.

You could also look into a solution that relies on inter-epic communication via different actions. That could get tricky depending on the complexity of your workflow, though. You'd need each action to uniquely identify sub-processes. Here's an idea:

```js
const fetchMultipleOperationsEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(OPERATIONS_FETCH_ALL),
  switchMap(({ payload }) =>
    merge(...payload.ids.map(processId =>
      concat(
        of(fetchOperations({ processId })),
        // Note: This keeps the observable running until either
        // the corresponding "success" or "failure" action is
        // dispatched:
        action$.pipe(
          filter(action => (action.type === FETCH_SUCCESS || action.type === FETCH_FAILURE) && action.payload.processId === processId),
          first(),
          ignoreElements(),
        ),
      )
    )).pipe(
      finalize(() => console.log('done')),
    )
  )
)

const fetchOperationsEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType(OPERATIONS_FETCH),
    mergeMap(({ payload }) => fetchOperationData(payload.processId))
)

const fetchOperationData = processId => {
    api.fetchOperationsByProcess(processId).pipe(
        // Note: We have to pass along the `processId` in the
        // "success" action so that the inner observables in
        // `fetchMultipleOperationsEpic` can complete:
        mergeMap(operations => of(fetchSuccess({ processId }), fooAction(), barAction())),
        catchError(error => of(fetchOperationsFailure({ processId, error })))
    )
}
```